# Android change Ringtone from activity

Tags: android, android-intent, mp3, ringtone

Well I found this code , after running this I got some activity (as Dialog) to choose from, so far so good. But my problem is that I want to choose some mp3 as my ringtone, how can I do that ?

This code give me only the default ringtones in the list:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent( RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
        intent.putExtra( RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,
        RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        intent.putExtra( RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone111");

        intent.putExtra( RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI,
        Uri.parse( "/sdcard/Slipknot - Spit It Out.mp3"));

        startActivityForResult( intent, 0);
```

Comment: Or maybe if this is not the way it should be done, than how can I change the ring tone of the phone to some mp3 on my sdcard ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution of this is to add folder ringtone in audio ( /sdcard/media/audio/ringtone/ )
and you can add mp3 in this folder so lather on they will be shown in the list

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**TYPE_ALL**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html)

Comment: I tried with TYPE_ALL but only give the same plus sounds for alarms and notifications nothing more, I still doesn't see any mp3 in the list

Comment: Can you check this url : http://maketecheasier.com/add-custom-alarm-ringtone-in-android/2010/01/08